# Hive SQL aggregate merge multiple sqls into one

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a serial sqls like:

```
select count(distinct userId) from table where hour >= 0 and hour <= 0;
select count(distinct userId) from table where hour >= 0 and hour <= 1;
select count(distinct userId) from table where hour >= 0 and hour <= 2;
...
select count(distinct userId) from table where hour >= 0 and hour <= 14;
```

Is there a way to merge them into one sql?

Comment: Try to use case when operation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to keep a cumulative count, bracketed by the hour. To do that, you can use a window function, like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  A.hour AS hour,
  SUM(COALESCE(M.include, 0)) OVER (ORDER BY A.hour) AS cumulative_count
FROM ( -- get all records, with 0 for include
  SELECT
    name,
    hour,
    0 AS include
  FROM
    table
  ) A
  LEFT JOIN
  ( -- get the record with lowest `hour` for each `name`, and 1 for include
    SELECT
      name,
      MIN(hour) AS hour,
      1 AS include
    FROM 
      table
    GROUP BY
      name
  ) M
  ON  M.name = A.name
  AND M.hour = A.hour
;
```

There might be a simpler way, but this should yield the correct answer in general.

#### Explanation:

This uses 2 subqueries against the same input `table`, with a derived field called `include` to keep track of which records should contribute to the final total for each bucket. The first subquery simply takes all records in the table and assigns `0 AS include`. The second subquery finds all unique `name`s and the lowest `hour` slot in which that `name` appears, and assigns them `1 AS include`. The 2 subqueries are `LEFT JOIN`'ed by the enclosing query.

The outermost query does a `COALESCE(M.include, 0)` to fill in any `NULL`'s produced by the `LEFT JOIN`, and those `1`'s and `0`'s are `SUM`'ed and windowed by `hour`. This needs to be a `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than using a `GROUP BY` becuse a `GROUP BY` will want both `hour` and `include` listed, but it ends up collapsing every record in a given `hour` group into a single row (still with `include=1`). The `DISTINCT` is applied after the `SUM` so it will remove duplicates without discarding any input rows.

Comment: this is not **distinct** count

Comment: Also distinct count is not additive. So distinct count for hour between 0 and 1 <> distinct count for hour 0 + distinct count for hour=1

Comment: It should be distinct userid, not distinct hour+count. What if the same user is twice in different hours

Comment: @leftjoin I updated this answer. This produces exactly the result I believe OP is after, and I think it takes care of your concerns as well.